# В IE не работает код при (document).ready а при (document).ajaxStop РАБОТАЕТ. Что за?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Привет

Стоит плагин liQuotes.js (который заменяет кавычки), подключен перед </body>:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.fn.liQuotes = function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            htmlreplace($(this));
            function htmlreplace(element){
                if (!element) element = document.body;
                var nodes = $(element).contents().each(function () {
                    if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        var result = $(this).text().replace(/\x27/g, '\x22').replace(/(\w)\x22(\w)/g, '$1\x27$2').replace(/(^)\x22(\s)/g, '$1&raquo;$2').replace(/(^|\s|\()"/g, "$1&laquo;").replace(/"(\;|\!|\?|\:|\.|\,|$|\)|\s)/g, "&raquo;$1")
                        $(this).after(result).remove();
                    } else {
                        htmlreplace(this);
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    };

   $('.content').liQuotes();

});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('.cert-bg').liQuotes();
    $('.logo-space').liQuotes();
    $('.search-space').liQuotes();
    $('.partners-bg').liQuotes();
    $('.video-blog').liQuotes();
    $('.project-bg').liQuotes();
});
```

Так вот во всех браузерах, кроме IE код работает корректно (при загрузке страницы заменяются кавычки, при ajax запросе аналогично - код отрабатывает в выбранных элементах). Но в IE не работает код при загрузке страницы. НО прекрасно работает при ajax запросе. Отключал все другие js коды, менял местами код запуска, менял на onload - не работает.

Пожалуйста, помогите - что исправить, чтобы заработал код в IE при загрузке страницы?

Comment: какой IE имеется ввиду?

Comment: Что значит _Но в IE не работает код при загрузке страницы_? Ничего не происходит? пишет ошибки в консоли? делает что-то еще?

Comment: jQuery.fn.liQuotes  - лучше вынести за `$(document).ready` - зачем дополнительная вложенность.

Comment: IE 11. Ничего не происходит, к сожалению, на IE не знаю как проверить консоль - знаю только firebug для mozila, но там все работает. Уточните, пожалуйста, про "вынести jQuery.fn.liQuotes" - как? Я просто взял чужой код, не знаю как он работает. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: На f12 консоль в ie11 тоже прекрасно открывается. Либо скажите что за ошибка чтобы я мог откалибровать свой хрустальный шар, либо приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, со всеми инклудами

Comment: Например, http://aksioma.me/2016/index(1).php?ID=1944, первая строчка новости "площадкой фестиваля "Outline 2016" должна" - вот в фразе "Outline 2016"  должны были измениться кавычки. Не работает. Перемудрил с кодами? В консоле ничего странного не увидел.

Comment: @Максим, `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference` -> index(1).php (174,13). Я бы не сказал, что это не странно

Comment: Это один недоработанный немного скрипт. Убрал его для чистоты эксперимента. Изменений нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в `iframe`. Когда IE доходит до него и пытается получить его содержимое получает

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
```

В качестве решения можно просто проверять, что текущий элемент не `iframe`, и если это `iframe`, то просто выходить из функции сразу.

Например:

```
if(element.tagName == 'IFRAME') return ;
```

Comment: Это действительно так! Супер, спасибо. Пожалуйста, уточните - а как сделать, чтобы IE проходил мимо этого iframe? iframe - это карта google

Comment: @Максим, можно например `tagName` проверять и если это IFRAME делать `return`. Это проверку не обязательно делать _только_ для IE - скорее всего это может падать по тем же причинам и в других браузерах, поэтому можно просто добавить строчку `if(element.tagName == 'IFRAME') return ;`